# Display excel sheet with charts in JSP

Tags: java, excel, jsp

I want to display excel sheet having excel charts in it on JSP page.
How I can display excel sheet on JSP? Sample code or library recommendation will help a lot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to read excel file 
and you can use any component based javascript libraries to display grid it in jsp or 
else you can write your own html. To compute formulas you can write in java code or if you want to make it dynamic, then you need some binding library like [Knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) or you can write your own javascript. 
And to display chart, there's no way you can display exact excel chart in jsp. But you can write a program to create similar chart using [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) or any javascript charting library for example [Potovis](http://mbostock.github.io/protovis/), [FusionChart](http://www.fusioncharts.com/), GoogleCharts, etc

Comment: Can you please explain how to display it in JSP page by reading? Any sample code will help

Comment: Requirement is to display existing charts not to create it again.